# Multihead attention model - IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to train a multiclass classification model (with 3 classes) using a multihead attention layer and two linear layers with some tabular data, and I'm getting this error:

> IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

I have copied my model/dataset classes and my training loop below; it seems like the error is associated with the data I am passing into my loss function (`criterion`), which looks like this:

y_pred: `tensor([-115.7523, -113.5820, 37.0307], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward0>)`

and

y: `tensor(0)`.

I am unable to resolve this error, so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the dataset and model classes:

```
class GeneExpressionDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.features = self.data.iloc[:, 2:].values
        self.labels = self.data.iloc[:, 1].values
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        features = torch.tensor(self.features[idx], dtype=torch.double)
        labels = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx], dtype=torch.long)
        return features, labels

class MultiheadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, num_heads, dropout_rate):
        super(MultiheadAttention, self).__init__()

        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate

        self.q_linear = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim)
        self.k_linear = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim)
        self.v_linear = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.out_linear = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim)

    def forward(self, query, key, value, mask=None):
        batch_size = query.size(0)

        # Apply linear transformations to obtain query, key, and value representations
        q = self.q_linear(query).view(batch_size, -1, self.num_heads)
        k = self.k_linear(key).view(batch_size, -1, self.num_heads)
        v = self.v_linear(value).view(batch_size, -1, self.num_heads)

        # Compute scaled dot-product attention scores
        scores = torch.matmul(q, k.transpose(1, 2)) / (self.input_dim ** 0.5)

        if mask is not None:
            mask = mask.unsqueeze(1)
            scores = scores.masked_fill(mask == 0, -1e9)

        # Apply softmax to obtain attention weights
        attn_weights = torch.softmax(scores, dim=-1)

        # Apply dropout to the attention weights
        attn_weights = self.dropout(attn_weights)

        # Compute the attention output
        attn_output = torch.matmul(attn_weights, v)

        # Concatenate the attention output from different heads
        attn_output = attn_output.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().view(batch_size, -1, self.num_heads * (self.input_dim // self.num_heads))

        # Apply linear transformation to obtain the final attention output
        out = self.out_linear(attn_output)

        return out

class geneGPT(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hid_dim, output_dim, num_heads, dropout_rate):
        super().__init__()
        self.attention = MultiheadAttention(input_dim, num_heads, dropout_rate)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(num_heads * (input_dim//num_heads), hid_dim)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.out = nn.Linear(hid_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, x, mask=None):
        x = self.attention(x, x, x, mask)
        x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.out(x)

        return x
```

and here is the training loop:

```
print('Training...')
model = geneGPT(INPUT_DIM, HID_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM, NUM_HEADS, DROPOUT_RATE).double().to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    train_losses = 0.0
    valid_losses = 0.0
    train_accs = 0.0
    valid_accs = 0.0
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_dl):
        x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = model(x).squeeze()
        y = y.squeeze()
        print(y_pred, y)
        train_loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
        train_acc = multi_acc(y_pred, y)
        train_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_losses += train_loss.item()
        train_accs += train_acc.item()
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(val_dl):
        x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
        y_pred = model(x).squeeze()
        y = y.squeeze()
        valid_loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
        valid_acc = multi_acc(y_pred, y)
        valid_losses += valid_loss.item()
        valid_accs += valid_acc.item()
    print("Epoch {}/{} | Loss: {:.4f} | Train Loss:{:.4f} | Valid Loss".format(epoch + 1, NUM_EPOCHS, train_loss / len(train_dl), valid_loss / len(val_dl)))
    print("Training Accuracy: {:.4f} | Validation Accuracy: {:.4f}".format(train_accs / len(train_dl), valid_accs / len(val_dl)))
test_accs = 0.0
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(test_dl):
    x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
    y_pred = model(x).squeeze()
    y = y.squeeze()
    test_acc = multi_acc(y_pred, y)
    test_accs += test_acc.item()
print("Testing Accuracy: {:.4f}".format(test_accs / len(test_dl)))
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model.pth")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your training loop

```
y_pred = model(x).squeeze()
y = y.squeeze()
```

You changed the dimension of both, and in later step

```
train_loss = criterion(y_pred.unsqueeze(0), y)
```

You again changed the y_pred dimension, keeping the y dim same. So I assume the relative difference in the dim of both y and y_pred is resulting in the error " Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (0)".

Comment: @Abishek Kumar, when I remove the y_pred.unsqueeze(0) in the training loop, I get this error: `IndexError: Dimensionout of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)`, which is why I tried to unsqueeze

Comment: can you print, the pred and y ?

Comment: @Abishek Kumar I have included those in the text of my question.

Comment: I tried to replicate the error on my end, and the problem seems to be dues to the shape of the input data. Can you print out the batch size, input dim, etc..